# Return value in template class in funcion can't rid of "warning not all control paths return a value"

Tags: c++, list, class, templates, warnings

i have problem with my code. I have tried everything what i know and i cant get rid of warning level 1. I have something like this:

```
template <class T>
T& aghSlist<T>::at(int n) const
{
   if ( (n < 0) || (n > size()))
      throw aException(0, "Index out of range", __FILE__, __LINE__);

   node * temp = head;
   int counter = 0;

   while (temp)
   {
      if (counter == n)
         return temp->data; //here probably is the reason of warning
      temp = temp->next;
      counter ++;
   }
}
```

So

param n - position in list;
size () - return size of list,
counter - param helpful to get to n position
temp - pointer to moving forward in list
head - beginning of the list

I 'm sure that all paths return a value, but i'm getting this warning. Is any possibility in c++ to return reference to NULL or in some other way resolve this problem?

Comment: if `temp` becomes null before `counter` equals `n` there is no return value. That is what the compiler is complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

A human reading your can conclude that, if your function has no bugs, the function will never go past the `while` statement. Hence, it might be OK to omit the `return` statement after the `while` statement. Your compiler is not able to deduce that. Hence, it expects a `return` statement after the `while` loop.

You can use something like the following to pacify the compiler:

```
while (temp)
{
   if (counter == n)
      return temp->data;
   temp = temp->next;
   counter ++;
}

// Code should never reach here.
// These lines are here solely to pacify the compiler
static T dummy{};
return dummy;
```

BTW, the logic of the conditional in the `if` statement is incorrect. Instead of

```
if ( (n < 0) || (n > size()))
```

it should be

```
if ( (n < 0) || (n >= size()))
```

For `n` to be a valid 0-based index, it has to be less than the size of the list.

Comment: No, if statement is correct because, if i have list:
head -> _ _ _ _ _ , size() = 4.
and i  want add item just on the back of list i use (for example), add (size(),T item), because place number 5 is empty and this add will be just pushend.

Comment: @Hangoverflow, that doesn't sound the right way to implement the class. However, you sound like you have a handle on that.

Answer (score 1):

`while(temp)` with `if (counter == n)`is redundant. Just `while(n--) { temp = temp->next;  } return temp->data` (You test the range at the beginning of the function)

Answer (score 1):

Dieter has suggested a better way to structure your function which avoids this issue entirely.

In cases where the algorithm is such that this is not possible, I'd put a `throw std::runtime_error("Unexpected code path!")` at the bottom of the function. That way, you silence the warning *and* if there is something that you missed, it will be properly reported.